# How to use one element in a list?

Tags: racket

I am trying to count if the song in the list is shorter than 300 seconds, but the first two tests didn't pass. It says it expects a song, but given a list. I wonder do I need to write other helper functions or I wrote the wrong function for the all-short?.

```
(define SONG-1
  (make-song
   "Redesigning Women"
   "The Highwomen"
   174 GENRE-COUNTRY
   #true))

(define SONG-2
  (make-song
   "Your Song"
   "Elton John"
   241 GENRE-POP
   #true))

(define SONG-3
  (make-song
   "All Along the Watchtower"
   "Jimi Hendrix"
   241 GENRE-ROCK
   #false))

(define SONG-4
  (make-song
   "Nessun Dorma"
   "Luciano Pavarotti"
   184 GENRE-CLASSICAL
   #false))
(define PL-0
  (make-pl "Quiet :)" '()))

(define PL-1
  (make-pl
   "Coding Beats"
   (list SONG-1 SONG-2
         SONG-3 SONG-4)))
(check-expect (all-short? PL-0)
              #false)

(check-expect (all-short? PL-1)
              #true)

(define (all-short? pl)
  (all-short?/los (pl-songs pl)))
(check-expect (all-short?/los SONG-1)
              #true)

(check-expect (all-short?/los SONG-2)
              #true)

(check-expect (all-short?/los SONG-3)
              #true)

(check-expect (all-short?/los SONG-3)
              #true)

(define (all-short?/los song)
  (if
   (< (song-duration song) 300)
   #true
   #false))
```

Comment: `all-short?/los`
 should take a list of songs, not a single song. (On a side note, `(if boolean-condition #true #false)` is commonly written `boolean-condition`, and `(if boolean-condition #false #true)` as `(not boolean-condition)`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you forgot to include a pre-defined list abstraction for the all-short? function.

Try something like:

```
(define (all-short? pl)
  (andmap all-short?/los (pl-songs pl)))
```

You could also simplify your all-short?/los function since they are boolean results.

Try something like:

```
(define (all-short/los song)
  (< (song-duration song) 300))
```